# Como impedir o start automatico de containers ao iniciar o Docker

Tags: docker

Tenho o Docker instalado em um MacOS, ao iniciar o aplicativo do Docker meus contêineres estão sendo iniciados automaticamente. Como faço para impedir este comportamento de start automático?

Comment: Verifique se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40513690/6510304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/start-containers-automatically/) ao definir o parâmetro **--restart= always** estarei configurando um restart automático em caso de stop, seja ele forçado ou não. Isso significa que, caso eu desligue a máquina e ligue novamente, ao iniciar um processo do Docker o container será iniciado junto.

Para impedir isso posso simplesmente omitir **--restart=** do meu docker-compose.yml, pois por default essa opção é igual a **no** (não iniciar automaticamente).

Outra alternativa seria atualizar essa opção diretamente nas definições do container:

```
docker update --restart=no meu-container
```

ou

```
docker update --restart=on-failure meu-container
```

No ultimo caso só irá ocorrer restart caso o container saia com um código de retorno diferente de zero.